# Have a col layout become a row layout once it drops below a min-width

Tags: css

I'd like to achieve the next result:
I have 2 columns with the right one filling the remaining width.
Once the right one drops below its min-width it has to go below the left colum and the left column should fill the whole width.
Is this possible using only css?

This is the closest I could get, but it doesn't work in FF and the leftcol obviously keeps its min-width of 100px when the rightcol drops below it.

```
#leftcol{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#rightcol{
    background-color: yellow;
    min-width: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your looking for is something like the 1140 Grid system.

See here; http://cssgrid.net/

Download and view the demo - by using media queries you can alter the width of your rows/cols depending on how wide the browser is :-)

Comment: Thanks, the media-queries they use is just what I needed!